# How to reference struct string member?

Tags: c++

I've struct:

```
struct User {
~User();
Datacratic::Id id;                     ///< Exchange-specific user ID
Datacratic::Id buyeruid;               ///< Exchange seat-specific user ID
Datacratic::TaggedInt yob;             ///< Year of birth
std::string gender;             ///< Gender: Male, Female, Other
Datacratic::CSList keywords;           ///< List of keywords of consumer intent
Datacratic::UnicodeString customdata;         ///< Custom data from exchange
Datacratic::Optional<Geo> geo;                   ///< Geolocation of user at registration
std::vector<Data> data;         ///< User data segments
Json::Value ext;   
}
```

When I reference gender by `user.gender`, it says:

```
error: âstruct Datacratic::Optional<OpenRTB::User>â has no member named âgenderâ
         result->segments.addStrings("gender", result->user.gender);
```

Thanks,
Ann

Comment: According to [its (extremely vague) documentation](http://rtbkit.org/dox/0.9/structOpenRTB_1_1Optional.html), `Datacratic::Optional` acts like a pointer. I only spotted this due to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/rtbkit.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/ibmezgov214). Does `result->user->gender` work?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add gender from user struct, but it complains. @Rhymoid

Comment: Does the compiler accept `result->segments.addStrings("gender", result->user->gender);`? If so, does it work as you expect it to work? If not, does the compiler give a different error?

Comment: Nop, that's why I used result->segments.addStrings("gender", result->user.gender) @Rhymoid

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler error it looks to me like `result->user` is of type `OpenRTB::User`, which may be distinct from your `struct User` class. So you to either make `result->user` of your type `User`, or extend the `OpenRTB::User` class and add your additional fields. You could then access your fields from a `OpenRTB::User *` by making a dynamic cast to `User *`.

Comment: Same, the Struct User is in the file that has namespace OpenRTB. How to dynamically cast it?

Comment: Your ```User``` should extend the ```OpenRTB::User``` in order to dynamically cast. Syntax is ```dynamic_cast<User *>(result->user)```. If you are certain you put a ```User *``` in ```result->user```, but ```User``` doesn't subclass ```OpenRTB::User```, then you'll have to do a ```reinterpret_cast```, with the same syntax as above.

Comment: The User is Datacratic::Optional<OpenRTB::User> user; Can you put it in code since I cast it inside: result->segments.addStrings("gender", result->user->gender) with dynamic_cast<User *>(result->user) or dynamic_cast<OpenRTB::User *>(result->user) WON'T work! @gg.kaspersky

Comment: error: expected type-specifier before âUserâ
             result->segments.addStrings("gender", (dynamic_cast<User *>(result->user))->gender);